# Is it possible to have a macro for a hashmap literal with "key: value" syntax?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

This [maplit](https://docs.rs/maplit/1.0.2/maplit/) crate allows hashmap literals with `=>` as a separator. I believe it's impossible to use `macro_rules!` to allow the `:` separator, but is it possible with a macro that processes a stream of tokens?

Is it impossible to add `{ key: value }` style macros to the language, even in the compiler?

I suspect the problem is conflict with the `:` type operator, but I cannot construct an ambiguous example where it is impossible for the compiler to make a decision of which way to interpret `:`.

Comment: You can likely achieve what you want with a [function-like procedural macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html#function-like-procedural-macros).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@kmdreko does a good job of explaining why you can't have an expression followed by a colon in a macro. However, you can work around that, by forcing the key to be a token tree rather than an expression:

```rust
macro_rules! hashmap{
    ( $($key:tt : $val:expr),* $(,)? ) =>{{
        #[allow(unused_mut)]
        let mut map = ::std::collections::HashMap::with_capacity(hashmap!(@count $($key),* ));
        $(
            #[allow(unused_parens)]
            let _ = map.insert($key, $val);
        )*
        map
    }};
    (@replace $_t:tt $e:expr ) => { $e };
    (@count $($t:tt)*) => { <[()]>::len(&[$( hashmap!(@replace $t ()) ),*]) }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58d26872f1fbf7a171d6578b3806bc3e)

The drawback of taking this route, as opposed to a procedural macro, which probably could handle this pattern just fine, is that most complex expressions will have to be wrapped in parentheses or curly brackets. For example,

```
let map = hashmap!{ 2 + 2 : "foo" };
```

won't work, but

```
let map = hashmap!{ (2 + 2) : "foo" };
```

will.

Comment: Amazing. I proposed adding this to maplit.

Comment: Thsi is truly incredible. I think it's the same way that the `json!()` macro in *serde-json* works for example, but this is still cool to see the explanation written out.

Comment: @rv.kvetch the `json!()` macro uses a much more complicated tt muncher that can parse `expr : expr`, and will promptly break whenever type ascriptions for expressions become a thing.

Comment: Hi Aiden4
Amazing to your code, but I dont understand "@replace @count" in the code; could you explain more or give some links?

Comment: @Henry, they're just markers for internal use by the macro. It just lets me effectively have sub-macros, without actually needing to define them. Take a look [here](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-internal-rules.html) for more information (do note the book is a bit out of date, but probably still the best resource for understanding `macro_rules!` available.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to replace the `=>` with a `:` in the `maplit!` macro you'd get this error:

```
error: `$key:expr` is followed by `:`, which is not allowed for `expr` fragments
 --> src/lib.rs:6:17
  |
6 |     ($($key:expr: $value:expr),*) => {
  |                 ^ not allowed after `expr` fragments
  |
  = note: allowed there are: `=>`, `,` or `;`
```

The specific problem is that the macro accepts any arbitrary expression as the key type. You could still have the `{ key: value }` syntax, but only if the `key` is an `ident` (for example) instead of an `expr`.

You can read the [Follow-set Ambiguity Restrictions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#follow-set-ambiguity-restrictions) section of Macros by Example in the Rust Reference:

> The parser used by the macro system is reasonably powerful, but it is limited in order to prevent ambiguity in current or future versions of the language.
>
> [...]
>
> `expr` and `stmt` may only be followed by one of: `=>`, `,`, or `;`.

That's not to say its necessarily ambiguous, though it may get confusing to parse in examples with a lot of `:`s like `MyEnum::Variant: ::std::collections::Vec::new()`. Its designed like that because only the documented tokens are *guaranteed* to indicate the end of an expression and other tokens *may become* ambiguous in the future.

You'll see though, that this only limits how `macro_rules!` patterns are handled and would not affect a procedural macro since you have free reign to decide how the tokens are parsed.

---

I tried to create a simple procedural macro using `syn` to aid in parsing expressions, but it chokes on the `Expr : Expr` syntax because it attempts to eagerly parse the first expression as a [type ascription expression](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.Expr.html#variant.Type) which is a yet-to-be-completed [feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23416). This is the kind of future expansion that the `macro_rules!` guards against.

Going with a token tree and using parenthesis for ambiguity in [Aiden4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541479/2189130) is the way to go if you really want `:` instead of `=>`. This still could be done with a procedural macro, but it would not be as readily available and would be ambiguous if type ascription expressions gets added to the language.

Comment: My question was about the procedular macros. Is it definitely possible with procedural macros?

Comment: @Test I edited my answer but it has a bit of an unsatisfying conclusion